# How to use a newly added tabLayout module as library in a project?

Tags: android, kotlin, module

I completed working on an app and now I want to add a tabLayout inside it so I add a new Tabbed Activity module from the presets, I designed the tabLayout as required but now I'm confused how to add the tabLayout in the Oncreate of the MainActivity.kt of the main app module. I am thinking of adding the tablayout activity as companion object. If you have any solution please help!!!
This is my tablayout activity(not sure about the companion object)-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

companion object tablayout {
    fun launchActivity(aciivity: Activity) {
        val intent = Intent(aciivity.MainActivity::class.java)
        aciivity.startActivity(intent)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val sectionsPagerAdapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(this, supportFragmentManager)
        val viewPager: ViewPager = binding.viewPager
        viewPager.adapter = sectionsPagerAdapter
        val tabs: TabLayout = binding.tabs
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
    }

}
```

Comment: You cannot use tab layout with different activities because for tablayout, you need to have different fragment for different tabs and that's how it's implemented so you will need to change activities to fragments in order to add tab layout to existing app.

Comment: @KaranMehta did you mean I have to manually create tablayout in the main module itself and it is not possible to add tabLyaout feature from the library module?

Comment: No you don't need to add tab layout manually but you need to convert the activities into fragments to use them inside the tabview.

Comment: @KaranMehta yes I have created individual fragments for each tab for the tablayout and implemented it as well  but, my question is how to add the tablayout feature by calling it from the mainactivity.kt in the main app module.